# Ember Data usage without a Backend API and converting Models to JSON (Ember 2.5.0)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember v2.5.0 without an external datastore.

After creating a record at the route using the createRecord method it cannot be queried for in other parts of the app (controller or components).

My understanding is that I need to use [store.push](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push) to save the record locally so that it may be accessed by the controller. However the store.push method requires the arguments to be in json format.

I could just do away with the models however I was wondering if there a quick way to convert the models into json format using Ember version 2.5.0?
I would also like to know if my assumptions on using store.push to persist the data locally is a recommended way to go when using Ember Data without an external backend.

There are other references on "Ember models to json" on stack overflow however they are outdated and I particularly would like to know if my approach/assumptions are correct and if not, what the alternatives are. Im very new to Ember.

**Problem**

```js
//Route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        let shape, square;

        square = this.store.createRecord('square');

        shape = this.store.createRecord('shape', {
            shared: 'shared-value',
            square: square
        });

        return shape;
    }
});

//Controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        someActionName() {
            console.log(this.store.peekRecord('shape', 1)); //undefined!
        }
    }
});

//Shape Model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    shared: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '' }),
    square: DS.belongsTo('square')
});

//Square Model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    sides: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '4' }),
    whereIbelong: DS.belongsTo('shape')
});
```

Comment: You're not "persisting locally", as soon as the person refreshes the tab everything is gone, is that what you want?

Comment: Yep thats what I desire. I used the wrong terminology, I meant persistence per session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using `store.push` is a good long-term approach, it's better to use the `save` and `destroyRecord` methods, as Ember Data expects.

You can create an adapter from the [base Adapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html) using local storage, or maybe just returning the record passed in `createRecord/updateRecord` works.

Experiment with it and find what works better for your use case, adapters are very flexible.

As a side note, the best way I found to make `store.push` work as expected is like this:

```js
var obj = {
    id: '1',
    name: "object name",
    // More object properties...
};
store.push(store.normalize('model-name', obj));
```

Comment: `store.pushPayload` exists so you don't have to call normalize yourself.

Comment: I don't think it's a good approach to write an adapter which simulates a `save` methods but does not persist the record. Save is just about persisting. So perhaps an adapter like described should throw if someone tries to save the record.

Comment: To be honest, I mentioned as a possibility, but I think the way to go in an Ember app without backend is persisting in the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

`createRecord` does not add an ID. So `this.store.peekRecord('shape', 1)` is undefined because your record created does not have an ID. Everything works well if you set an ID for your record.

Ember Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/e2b24b5a2cdab19c7b7401c57aff9959?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

If your goal is to persist records on client side have a look at [ember-local-storage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage).